# openssl connection on a self-cerficated server

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm performing this command in order to check whether I'm able to create a SSL connection:

```
openssl s_client -connect private-server:5000
```

`private-server` is a server I've set up with a self-generated certificate.

The output is:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
140180300502672:error:140790E5:SSL routines:ssl23_write:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 308 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1467812448
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

What I need to get the connection right?
Thanks.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 1):

> SSL handshake **has read 0 bytes** and written 308 bytes

The client has started with the SSL handshake but the server has closed the connection without sending anything back. There might be a lot of reasons for this like a firewall blocking the connection, various configuration errors on the server, server not expecting TLS at all, server expecting SNI ...

Unfortunately it can not be said from the information you provide which exactly is the cause of the problem. You might try with different clients (browser) to find out, if the problem is more at the server or middlebox site (i.e. none of the clients work) or if it is more a problem which can maybe fixed on the client site (some clients work, others not).